# Split POS tagged textvectors/factors into sentences with R - regex

Tags: regex, r, text, split, pos-tagger

Please help me for my small project.

A text element (factor) has sentences (actually a list of many text elements). The text is POS tagged. I need to separate the single sentences into separate elements.

I guess, I have to match all `"./$. ", "!/$. ", "?/$. "`, etc. with some R function and save the output as a list of factors. Each factor being a sentence.

A sample text & code:

```
library(stingr)

# Input vector/factor with "/$. " separated sentences

r <- c("Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV tÃ¤glichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ./$. In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR BÃ¼chern/NN gefÃ¼llt/VVPP ,/$, jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA StÃ¼ck/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN !/$. Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lÃ¤sst/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$, dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/$, besonders/ADV fÃ¼r/APPR BÃ¼cher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ./$.")

# output list of vectors/factors with splited sentences as list elements
(r.listOfSent <- as.list(strsplit(as.character(r), "//$.")))
> r.sentlist
[[1]]
 [1] "Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV tÃ¤glichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ."                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [2] " In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR BÃ¼chern/NN gefÃ¼llt/VVPP ,/$, jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA StÃ¼ck/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN ."                                                                
 [3] " Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lÃ¤sst/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$, dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/$, besonders/ADV fÃ¼r/APPR BÃ¼cher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
# input
r <- "Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV tÃ¤glichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ./$. In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR BÃ¼chern/NN gefÃ¼llt/VVPP ,/$, jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA StÃ¼ck/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN !/$. Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lÃ¤sst/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$, dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/$, besonders/ADV fÃ¼r/APPR BÃ¼cher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ./$."

# function to split sentences at commas, periods and other punctuation marks
# really we're just splitting at /$ in the string
r.listOfSent <- unlist(strsplit(r, "\\$."))

# output
[1] "Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV tÃ¤glichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ./"                                      
[2] " In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR BÃ¼chern/NN gefÃ¼llt/VVPP ,/"
[3] " jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA StÃ¼ck/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN !/"                                                             
[4] " Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lÃ¤sst/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/"                                                         
[5] " dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/"                                                                                                                                              
[6] " besonders/ADV fÃ¼r/APPR BÃ¼cher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ./"
```

If that's not right, please edit your question to show a sample of the output you desire.

**UPDATE** thanks to some clarifying comments from alex and Blue Magister, here's how to produce the desired output:

```
# function to split the string on the literal $.
r.listOfSent  <- strsplit(r, "/$.", fixed=TRUE)

# which gives
[[1]]
[1] "Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV tÃ¤glichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ."                                                                                                                                                      
[2] " In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR BÃ¼chern/NN gefÃ¼llt/VVPP ,/$, jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA StÃ¼ck/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN !"
[3] " Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lÃ¤sst/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$, dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/$, besonders/ADV fÃ¼r/APPR BÃ¼cher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ."
```

Comment: `.` in your pattern is being treated as "any character" when instead you want the literal `.` I suggest `strsplit(r, "/\\$\\.")` or `strsplit(r, "/$.", fixed=TRUE)`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, since splitting on the literal `.`  will fail to split on the `,` and `!` and `?` which seems to be what the question is asking for...

Comment: **@BlueMagister** `strsplit(r, "/$.", fixed=TRUE)` works :) Tank you!

Comment: @Ben wanted to split only sentences, without `,`. Thank you.

Comment: @alex your question is ambiguous, you say 'I need to separate the single sentences into separate elements' (ie. spit each sentence into parts) and include `,` in your list of characters to match. Please take more care when asking questions to ensure you get the answer you really need.

Comment: @Ben Thank you. I'm bit new and have to accomodate. Sorry for the ambiguos question. I explicitly wanted/want (have to test a bit) only sentences contained between a capital letter and a full stop. no `,` or `;` originally. Best Regards :)